# __git_ps1: command not found

Tags: docker, sh, git-bash

(yes I know, that there are similar questions, but none from them helped me).

Pre-condition:
I want to build docker containers "from Windows" (8.1).
I installed/did:

- docker tools
- added .sh to PATH variable
- gitbash
- I ran docker quickstart terminal, and opened gitbash

Flow:
1) I just checkouted needed project with Dockerfile, and tried to build(in power shell, or git bash) with

```
$docker build -t IMAGENAME .
```

and it failed on one of "steps" with

```
/bin/sh: /app/dirname/update.sh: not found
```

2) If i'm trying just to run

```
$sh
```

from git bash, it failes with mentioned in topic

```
sh: __git_ps1: command not found
```

Any ideas how to resolve this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue today.  I found this link https://dzone.com/articles/bash-gitps1-command-not-found. Since I was on Windows 8 and using git-bash, I did this in my %USERHOME%/.bash.rc file:

```
if [ -f /c/Users/me/AppData/Local/Programs/Git/mingw64/share/git/completion/git-prompt.sh ]; then
. /c/Users/me/AppData/Local/Programs/Git/mingw64/share/git/completion/git-prompt.sh
```

fi

and the problem went away :)